# free software to create lottie animated stickers for telegram

Tags: open-source, animation, vector-graphics

I know telegram uses the lottie format by Adobe After Effects - [See here](https://core.telegram.org/stickers)

I would like to make some tests and I don't want to spend money purchasing Adobe software licenses for that.

How can I do high-quality telegram animated stickers (or lottie animations in general) with free / open-source software? What other softwares other than Adobe After Effects would allow me to animate and produce lottie files?